# Unable to load asset en.json

Tags: json, flutter, android-studio, dart

I have declared my assets in pubspec.yaml the right way and I have declared it in my app... the app runs but on the emulator I get a message Unable to load assets: "assets/translation/en.json". The asset does not exist or has empty data... but when I open it there is data
this is my pubspec.yaml:
[image: As you can see in the picture I have declared the assets in the pubspec.yaml, it is also in my project directory]

when I open the en.json I can see data in it:
[image: This here is the en.json file in translation directory. it has data too..]

I don't know why it runs but the emulator shows this:
[image: This is what is seen on the emulator..]

This is how I called the en.json using easy_localization package in flutter:
This is main.dart:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:kimathilegal_app/app.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

import 'models/constants.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  Hive.init(directory.path);
  await Hive.openBox(Constants.bookmarkTag);
  await Hive.openBox(Constants.recentSearchTag);
  await Hive.openBox(Constants.notificationTag);
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
      statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark));




  runApp(
    EasyLocalization(
      supportedLocales: const [Locale('en'), Locale('ar'), Locale('es')],
      path: 'assets/translation',
      fallbackLocale: const Locale('en'),

      //Default language
      startLocale: const Locale('en'),
      useOnlyLangCode: true,
      child: const MyApp(),
    )
  );
}
```

and this is app.dart:

```
import 'package:firebase_analytics/firebase_analytics.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:kimathilegal_app/pages/splash_page.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'blocs/ads_bloc.dart';
import 'blocs/category_bloc.dart';
import 'blocs/category_tab1_bloc.dart';
import 'blocs/category_tab2_bloc.dart';
import 'blocs/category_tab3_bloc.dart';
import 'blocs/category_tab4_bloc.dart';
import 'blocs/featured_bloc.dart';
import 'blocs/latest_articles_bloc.dart';
// import 'blocs/notification_bloc.dart';
import 'blocs/popular_articles_bloc.dart';
import 'blocs/settings_bloc.dart';
import 'blocs/tab_index_bloc.dart';
import 'blocs/theme_bloc.dart';
import 'blocs/user_bloc.dart';
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';
import 'models/theme.dart';


final FirebaseAnalytics firebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.instance;
final FirebaseAnalyticsObserver firebaseObserver =  FirebaseAnalyticsObserver(analytics: firebaseAnalytics);

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeBloc>(
      create: (_) => ThemeBloc(),
      child: Consumer<ThemeBloc>(
        builder: (_, mode, child) {
          return MultiProvider(
              providers: [
                ChangeNotifierProvider<SettingsBloc>(create: (context) => SettingsBloc()),
                ChangeNotifierProvider<CategoryBloc>(create: (context) => CategoryBloc()),
                ChangeNotifierProvider<FeaturedBloc>(create: (context) => FeaturedBloc()),
                ChangeNotifierProvider<LatestArticlesBloc>(create: (context) => LatestArticlesBloc()),
                ChangeNotifierProvider<UserBloc>(create: (context) => UserBloc()),
                // ChangeNotifierProvider<NotificationBloc>(create: (context) => NotificationBloc()),
                ChangeNotifierProvider<PopularArticlesBloc>(create: (context) => PopularArticlesBloc()),
                ChangeNotifierProvider<AdsBloc>(create: (context) => AdsBloc()),
                ChangeNotifierProvider<TabIndexBloc>(create: (context) => TabIndexBloc()),
                ChangeNotifierProvider<CategoryTab1Bloc>(create: (context) => CategoryTab1Bloc()),
                ChangeNotifierProvider<CategoryTab2Bloc>(create: (context) => CategoryTab2Bloc()),
                ChangeNotifierProvider<CategoryTab3Bloc>(create: (context) => CategoryTab3Bloc()),
                ChangeNotifierProvider<CategoryTab4Bloc>(create: (context) => CategoryTab4Bloc()),

              ],
              child: MaterialApp(
                  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                  supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales,
                  localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,
                  navigatorObservers: [firebaseObserver],
                  locale: context.locale,
                  theme: ThemeModel().lightTheme,
                  darkTheme: ThemeModel().darkTheme,
                  themeMode: mode.darkTheme == true ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light,
                  home: const SplashPage()
              )
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Wolfeeee, a small distraction make world worse, so change this  `path: 'assets/translation'` in  `path: 'assets/translations'`  (you are missing the final 's')

Comment: oh yh... thanks so much.. did not see that.. teehee :D... like how you called me tho.. Wolfeee... seems like you know me... that's how my friends call me.. haha.. Thanks again